# Interrupting R Script?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358524/what-function-to-interrupt-the-running-r-script) which answers how to exit a function when needed. But I'm working with a complex R script which I'm debugging. I run it in VScode, and would be nice if there was a command to simply stop running the script altogether, as using `exit(1)` in python. See the code below for example.

```
rm(list=ls()) # Ensuring workspace starts off clean

a <- 1 # Do stuff I'm confident about
b <- 2 # Stuff I need to check if worked

cat(b)

Function_to_Stop_Execution_Here() # What can I for about this?

Stuff_I_dont_want_to_run()
```

Comment: Why not delete `Stuff_I_dont_want_to_run()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop a script, use `stop` (which raises an error).

If you possibly want to restart, but need to examine the working state, consider `browser`

```r
a <- 1 # Do stuff I'm confident about
b <- 2 # Stuff I need to check if worked

cat(b)
browser() # or stop("Some error message")
```

But if there is stuff you don't want to run below this, it's probably best to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`quit` or `q`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html). ]

However, `quit` will also completely quit R. If you want to return to the R console after your function to stop execution, you can use [`stopifnot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/stopifnot) to purposefully throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `quit()` with argument `save='ask'` and type `'c'` in console then.

```
a <- 1 # Do stuff I'm confident about
b <- 2 # Stuff I need to check if worked

cat(b)

quit(save='ask')
```