# Configuring the R console so that it stops executing a list of commands whenever one command fails

Tags: r

I sometimes paste  a list of commands to be executed in the R console. By default, if one command fails (i.e., raises an error), the R console indicates the command has failed, then executes the subsequent commands.

Is there any way to configure the R console so that it stops executing a list of commands whenever one command fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent execution of further code steps after error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573660/how-to-prevent-execution-of-further-code-steps-after-error)

Comment: There is some overlap but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of pasting, run this R command:

```
source("clipboard")
```

or if you want to see commands as well as output:

```
source("clipboard", echo = TRUE)
```

(or set the `verbose` option to avoid having to specify echo each time, i.e. `options(verbose = TRUE)` )

Comment: Thanks, that looks very useful too. (obviously the first time I tried `source("clipboard", echo = TRUE)`, I had `source("clipboard", echo = TRUE)` in the clipboard :) ). Also works in PuTTY.

Answer (score 3):

One strategy is to wrap the code in `{ }` so that the code is executed as a single block. For example,

```
{ceiling(quantile(rnorm(20), seq(0, 1, length.out=8))); rnorm(10)}
```

will run, but

```
{ceiling(quantile(rnorm(20), seq(0, 8, length.out=8))); rnorm(10)}
```

will error out and the second command, `rnorm(10)` will not run.

---

d.b. mentions in the comments setting the `options(error)`. According to `?options`, by default, this is set to `NULL`. If you want the code to stop at an error and enter debugging mode, you could type

```
options(error=recover)
```

in an initial session or put this into your .Rprofile and then R will enter a debugging mode upon hitting an error.

For the code above, you would see

```
{ceiling(quantile(rnorm(20), seq(0, 8, length.out=8))); rnorm(10)}
```

> Error in quantile.default(rnorm(20), seq(0, 8, length.out = 8)) :
>     'probs' outside [0,1]
>
> Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit
>
> 1: #1: quantile(rnorm(20), seq(0, 8, length.out = 8))
>   2: quantile.default(rnorm(20), seq(0, 8, length.out = 8))

Comment: @d.b I don't use this regularly, but added some text to address your comment. If you want to add a separate answer that adds more details, I would delete this and up vote yours.